# Xcode - How do I get back the find/replace on top of the coding window?

Tags: xcode

When you pressed CMD F on older versions of Xcode you got the find/replace window embedded on the coding window, instead of having a separate window floating around.

In Xcode 3.1.4, I have this annoying floating window.

Is there a way to get back the old and good find/replace box embedded on the coding window on this new release of Xcode?

thanks!

Comment: new release? the newest publicly available release of Xcode is 3.2.1, which behaves as you would like.

Comment: I'd like to know the opposite, actually—the "find banner" makes find-and-replace a huge, click-ridden pain, and removes, for instance, the "replace all in selection" function.

Comment: 3.2.1 is beta and you cannot use it to create final products. The latest approved release is 3.1.4.

Comment: Mike: 3.2.1 is not beta.

Comment: 3.2.2 is beta, 3.2.1 is the latest publicly available version of Xcode

Comment: what OS are you developing on? Tiger? Panther?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you pressed CMD F on older versions of Xcode you got the find/replace window embedded on the coding window, instead of having a separate window floating around.

You mean *newer* versions, right? It was introduced in 3.2.

> In Xcode 3.1.4, I have this annoying floating window.
>
> Is there a way to get back the old and good find/replace box embedded on the coding window on this new release of Xcode?

3.1.x isn't new. 3.2.x is new. The new release of Xcode already has it. The older releases don't have it at all.

Answer (score 2):

In 3.2.1, the find box is embedded in the relevant windows for me, and I can't find a setting to even change that.  Unless it's a hidden preference (and I can't find one on Secrets), upgrading should do it for you.

Comment: according to Apple (see developer site) 3.2.1 cannot be used for development.

Comment: Mike: What? That's all Xcode can be used for. Do you have a link to the specific statement you're referring to?

Comment: 3.2.1 is the latest version that is publicly available. 3.1.4 is way old.